# Editing objects in a list?

Tags: python, list

I'm making a program that keeps track of a number of things for a number of people, but I'm having an issue. My code looks like this:

```
johnny_appleseed = ["", 1]

def add_hour(name, hours):
    name[1] += hours

def edit_profile():
    input_name = input("Profile to edit: ")
    hours = input("Hours to add: ")
    name = input_name.lower().replace(" ", "_")
    add_hour(name, hours)
```

edit_profile()

However, when I type "Johnny Appleseed" into the `"Profile to edit: "` input and select a number of hours, it gives me the following error for the line `name[1] += hours`:

`TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment`

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: `add_hour(johnny_appleseed, hours)`?

Comment: The whole point of the function of edit_profile is that I can edit ANY profile based on the input of the user, not just johnny_appleseed's.

Answer (score 0):

What I think your problem is that you think that are confusing the string "johnny_appleseed" with the variable johnny_appleseed, they aren't the same thing. If you wanted to keep track of the number of hours worked for various people, you could use a dictionary. I've worked on your code to implement the dictionary part.

```
people = {"johnny_appleseed" : 1}
def add_hour(name, hours):
    people[name] += hours
def edit_profile():
    name = str(raw_input("Profile to edit: "))
    hours = int(raw_input("Hours to add: "))
    name = name.lower().replace(" ", "_")
    add_hour(name, hours)
```

With this implementation, you can use the strings that you are getting to index values in a python dictionary. If you wanted to add a new person, you would just do... people["sam"] = 0. Then there would be a new person "sam" in your people dictionary with 0 hours worked.

So, your mistake is that you think that you can call the variable johnny_appleseed with the string of the same name, you can't. You have to do something else.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no variable called `johnny_appleseed`.  Besides, in reality each list has four or five items, not just two.

Comment: Unless I didn't understand your question and I'm way off, johnny_appleseed=["", 1] is a variable and you are trying to access that variable in the add_hour function with the string "johnny_applesseed". Also, you can put a list into a dictionary, people = {"johnney_appleseed" : [4, whatever_else] }

Comment: Well, sure, the string's contents is `"johnny_appleseed"`, but the name of the string is `name`.  And if I were to add the list into the dictionary, how would I edit items in that list?  (I'm considering doing that - it sounds like the most efficient)

Comment: One, the fact that name of the string "johnny_applessed" is the variable name is irrelevant. name[1] += hours and "johnny_appleseed"[1] += hours are identical. This is why your getting the error saying strings objects do not support item assignment. Anyway to edit a list in a dictionary, you would write people["johnny_applessed"][ index_you_want ] = (whatever)